# 2004 Honda Pilot wont start

Tags: engine, honda, starting, pilot

I have a 2004 honda Pilot. Ok look carefully it has 510,453 miles on it. It wont start. I had a bad alternator for 2 weeks over charging my battery. I changed it. New spark plugs also. So 2 days ago i started it up drove 2 blocks and all yhe lights came on the then it broke down. I re started it and again it broke down. Now it does nothing but crank like it wants to start but dont. So i took it to a mechanic and they said it seems like the timing. And with the miles on it, it would be useless to pay that much for that repair. Do yall have any other reason why or a solution i have? Please help me.

Comment: Wow, now that's some serious mileage! I understand your pain, but I think the mechanic is right as that's what it sounds like to me as well. Which engine does your Pilot have?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I think the Pilot only comes with the 3.5l V6

Comment: Regardless of mileage if the engine ran OK before and the timing belt only slipped a tooth and has good compression I don't see a reason not to fix it. Book time on a timing belt R&R for the 3.5 is only 4 hours.

Comment: You took it to a mechanic and they said they think its the timing? I'd take it to another mechanic and pay to have the problem troubleshooted.

Comment: Ben is correct. The 3.5L i-VTEC came along in 2008 and the VCM VTEC was introduced in 2006, so this is a plain 3.5L VTEC engine.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, that's a lot of miles!  This doesn't sound much like a timing issue to me.  Typically when an engine just cranks and doesn't turn over it's either caused by problems with fuel delivery or ignition.  I would take it to another mechanic and let them take a look at it.  Chances are it's not too big of a repair.  Hopefully, it's only a fuel pump or ignition coil.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds exactly like a slipped timing belt to me. Honda spec'ed replacement every 105,000 miles back in 2004, they usually have some reserve, but I would never let one go more than 200K miles. How long has it been since the last timing belt replacement?

Fixing it might be affordable with one caveat- this is an interference engine. If a cam has only shifted one notch, it might be fine. If the valves are bent, the engine (and vehicle) is a write-off.